# How to update records in a table from 1 database based on query from another table in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have 2 tables

Database 1 total:

```
lcustomerid    sbarcode    dtreplicated
----------------------------------------
NULL             1           NULL
NULL             2           NULL
NULL             3           NULL
1353             4           12/6/15
```

Database 2 table :

```
lcustomerid     sbarcode     
-------------------------
12353             1
15353             2
53332             3
1353              4
```

What I'd like to do is make database 1 table look like this:

```
lcustomerid    sbarcode    dtreplicated
----------------------------------------
12353             1           NULL
15353             2           NULL
53332             3           NULL
1353              4           12/6/15
```

If I run this query - I'm able to put together the link between the 2 databases.

```
SELECT     
    Customers.lCustomerID, Customers.sBarcode, Web.sBarcode AS WebBarcode
FROM
    Customers 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    database1.db1.dbo.customers AS Web ON Web.sBarcode = Customers.sBarcode
WHERE     
    (Web.lCustomerid IS NULL) AND (Web.dtReplicated = '1/1/1900')
```

How can I update lcustomerid in database 1, based on results from database 2 where the barcodes match.  Based on the query above, I'll be running the query from database 2 (it's setup as a linked server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `join`:

```
update c
    set lcustomerid = cc.lcustomerid
    from database1.db1.dbo.customers c join
         Customers  cc
         on cc.barcode = c.barcode
    where lcustomerid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly update table1 from table2

```
UPDATE database1.db1.dbo.customers  SET lcustomerid = cc.lcustomerid FROM Customers CC 
 WHERE cc.barcode = barcode AND lcustomerid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE db1 SET customer_id = a.customer_id 
FROM 
(
    SELECT COALESCE(db1.customer_id, db2.lcustomerid) 
    AS customer_id, db1.sbarcode, db1.dtreplicated 
    FROM db1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN db2 ON db1.sbarcode = db2.sbarcode
) a
```